# Watchkit Multi-line label with Top Aligment

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit, watch

Want to add a multi-line label to a tablerowcontroller with top alignment.  The only alignment options are left/right etc.  Looks like it automatically centers the text vertically.  Anyway to force top alignment?
Using iOS8/Xcode 6.3.2

[image: The screen shows the multi-line label on the right but the text is centered vertically rather than aligned to the top]

Answer (score 1):

`Table Row Controller` is a **Group**.
You can change the **Group** Layout to Vertical.

You can also insert a **Group** into another **Group**, and control individual layout. Nested groups can help you to fine-tune the layout you desire:

[image]

> Nest a *vertical* group into the *horizontal* group to handle the label under the icon. Set the **Position** of the multiple lines label to *left* & *top*.

[image]

Comment: Updated my post to clarify better.  This is the single label to the right of the screenshot.  The label text in this multi-line label is vertically centered rather than aligned to the top

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using Xamarin, right-click on your storyboard file, and open it in Xcode Interface Builder. Click on the the label, and set the "Lines" property to 2 (or more). And make sure the size of it is set to "Size to fit content", same with any parent container/group.