# How can i set lineBreakMode to wordwrap in WKInterfaceLabel?

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch, wkinterfacelabel

Can anyone help me to set a lineBreakMode to wordWrap in WKInterfaceLabel in my watch app?

I tried with setAttributedText but didn't get any success. Here is my code for the same. I am using swift as programming language.

```
    let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 15);

    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle();
    style.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping;

    let attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
        .font: font,
       .paragraphStyle: style,
    ];

    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: getPromptText(), attributes: attributes)

    lblDisplayText.setAttributedText(attributedString);
```

Comment: Have you set `lblDisplayText.numberOfLines = 0` ?

Comment: Yes @SagarChauhan

Comment: Please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31352690/watchkit-multi-line-label-with-top-aligment